# Rewrite ruby code to remove repetition with dynamic variable names

Tags: ruby, oop, dry

I'm learning about OOD and I've been restructuring some code into classes. I have three identical pieces of code which open up a file and feed the contents into a hash:

```
# Build grade objects and insert into hash
pass_fail_array = load_csv(pass_fail_file)
grade_collection = pass_fail_array.map{ |e| Grade.new(e) }

grade_hash = {}

grade_collection.each do |x|
    grade_hash[x.mark.to_s] = x
end

# Build student objects and insert into hash
student_array = load_csv(student_file)
student_collection = student_array.map{ |e| Student.new(e) }

student_hash = {}

student_collection.each do |x|
    student_hash[x.full_name] = x
end

# students = {:array_name = "student_array",}

# Build course objects and insert into hash
course_array = load_csv(course_catalog_file)
course_collection = course_array.map{ |e| Course.new(e) }

course_hash = {}

course_collection.each do |x|
    course_hash[x.course.to_s] = x
end
```

When I first attempted to rewrite this as a method I wasn't sure how to name the collections which I'm generating - the `grade_hash`, `course_hash`, and `student_hash`.

I thought, possibly this should be a class, since this scrap of code is about generating copies of collections? It would be really helpful to see how the general principles are applied in this specific circumstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If the solution is dynamic variable names, you now have two problems.***

In general, if you're ever tempted to use dynamic variable names the answer is either a Hash, an Array, or a function. In this case, a function is appropriate. Use the [extract method refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

*Note: My Ruby is rusty, apologies for coding mistakes. And I'm going to leave the algorithm basically as is because that's not the point.*

Start with one of the duplicated code blocks.

```
# Build grade objects and insert into hash
pass_fail_array = load_csv(pass_fail_file)
grade_collection = pass_fail_array.map{ |e| Grade.new(e) }

grade_hash = {}

grade_collection.each do |x|
    grade_hash[x.mark.to_s] = x
end
```

Turn it into a function by wrapping it in a function declaration and returning the product of the code block: `grade_hash`.

```
def load_from_csv()
    pass_fail_array = load_csv(pass_fail_file)
    grade_collection = pass_fail_array.map{ |e| Grade.new(e) }

    grade_hash = {}

    grade_collection.each do |x|
        grade_hash[x.mark.to_s] = x
    end

    return grade_hash
end
```

Note which variables are declared outside the function, just `pass_fail_file` so pass that in.

```
def load_from_csv(file)
    pass_fail_array = load_csv(file)
    grade_collection = pass_fail_array.map{ |e| Grade.new(e) }

    grade_hash = {}

    grade_collection.each do |x|
        grade_hash[x.mark.to_s] = x
    end

    return grade_hash
end
```

Replace the code with a function call.

```
grade_hash = load_from_csv(pass_fail_file)
```

Extracting the method is the first, rote step in removing duplication.

---

Now we need to try and make that function work for the other cases. There's only two things different in each code block...

1. The class to make new objects for.
2. Which field to put into the hash.

The first one is easy enough, you can pass in the class name. That suggests this might work as a class method.

The second is a little trickier. You could pass in a function which says how to translate to the hash. But these are objects, take advantage. Instead of telling the class how to load its objects from a CSV, ask the class to load objects from the CSV for you. That means definitely making it a class method.

To deal with the problem of the hash key, define a method which says how to get a key for a CSV hash and use that.

```
# In each class define how to get the key for the CSV
def csv_key
    return mark.to_s
end

# In a mixin, put a generic way to load from a CSV
def self.load_from_csv(file)
    from_csv = load_csv(file)
    objs = from_csv.map{ |e| new(e) }

    objs.each do |x|
        hash[x.csv_key] = x
    end

    return hash
end
```

This one method is probably doing too much, split into two. One to load objects from the CSV, and one to turn an Array of objects into a hash.

```
def self.load_from_csv(file)
    return load_csv(file).map{ |e| self.new(e) }
end

def self.hash_from_objects(objs)
    objs.each do |x|
        hash[x.csv_key] = x
    end

    return hash
end
```

Then...

```
grades = Grade.hash_from_objects(
    Grade.load_from_csv(pass_fail_file)
)

students = Student.hash_from_objects(
    Student.load_from_csv(student_file)
)

courses = Course.hash_from_objects(
    Course.load_from_csv(course_catalog_file)
)
```

This is not a great interface, but you can see how it's moving away from [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) where you tell the objects what to do, and toward an object interface where you *ask* the objects what to do.

---

Next step is to really think about separating loading objects from the objects being loaded.

Notice that the function knows almost nothing about the objects it's loading. This suggests the next step would be to make a [Factory class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to load objects from a CSV rather than having this as part of the object interface itself. The CSV loader factory object would know the CSV file and the class. It would use the class's `csv_key` method.

```
class CSVLoader
    attr_reader :file, :class

    def load
        hash = {}
        load_csv(@file).map{ |e| @class.new(e) }.each do |x|
            hash[ x.csv_key ] = x
        end

        return hash
    end
end

grades = CSVLoader.new( file: pass_fail_file, class: Grade ).load
students = CSVLoader.new( file: student_file, class: Student ).load
courses = CSVLoader.new( file: course_catalog_file, class: Course ).load
```

That's a pretty good start.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is so helpful. I can see how you took it step by step, and the resources you linked are great. I can start to see the application of how to think through interfaces. I was confused at first about whether the loading behavior should qualify as a class since I didn't think I wanted multiple instances of it, but the way you stepped through it helps me to see a bit more about how to apply the 'factory class' pattern, thank you for that as well